# How to save and open the content in the one of subforms separately?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

There are two forms, a MainForm and a GraphicsForm.
In MainForm, there are "New" and "Save", "Open" buttons. When clicking the "New", a GraphicsForm created (When the "New" is clicked multiple times, multiple GraphicsForms are created).

The question is, when created multiple GraphicsForms, and the user only wants to save the content in one of them or open a content file to one of them, How to implement this?

MainForm.cs

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private ToolStripMenuItem _winMenuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem();
    private GraphicsForm _graphicsForm;
    private int _counter = 1;
    private ContentDoc _contentDoc = new ContentDoc();

    private void New_Click(objec sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _winMenuItem.Name = "Win";
        _winMenuItem.Text = "Windows";
        int item = MainMenuStrip.Items.IndexOf(_winMenuItem);
        if (item == -1)
        {
            MainMenuStrip.Items.Add(_winMenuItem);
            MainMenuStrip.MdiWindowListItem = _winMenuItem;
        }

        _graphicsForm = new GraphicsForm(_contentDoc);
        _graphicsForm.Name = string.Concat("Win_", _counter.ToString());
        _graphicsForm.Text = _graphicsForm.Name;
        _graphicsForm.MdiParent = this;
        _graphicsForm.Show();
        _graphicsForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        _counter++;
    }

    private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ... // here
    }

    private void Open_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ... // here
    }
}
```

GraphicsForm.cs

```
public partial class GraphicsForm : Form
{
    //ContentDoc is a class to manage all the graphics drawn by the user in the form.
    private ContentDoc _contentDoc = new ContentDoc();

    public GraphicsForm(ContentDoc contentDoc)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _contentDoc = contentDoc;
    }

    private Canvas_MouseDown()
    {
    }
    
    private Canvas_Paint()
    {
    }
    
    ...
```

Comment: Why are you assigning a new `ContentDoc` to your field where it's declared and then immediately replacing that with the `ContentDoc` object passed into the constructor? Don't create objects that you're never going to use.

Comment: What should I do to be correct? `ContentDoc` contains lists about the coordinates of the different graphics drawn by the user. Can you show me code example? I'm new to programming.

Comment: Youi may be new to programming but you're not new to logic. Think about the logic first and write code to implement that logic. You should be able to explain the logic behind any code you write. If you can't, why did you write it? Even if it's wrong, you should still be able to explain why you thought it was right. I already told you what to do. Now you just have to do it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes. Thanks for your advice. I got'em. code forever, young forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent form has an `ActiveMdiChild` property, so you can use the to access the currently-selected `GraphicsForm` instance:

```cs
var activeGraphicsForm = ActiveMdiChild as GraphicsForm;
```

There are other variations you might use, e.g. pattern matching, depending on the specific details and your preference.

You can then put your saving logic in a public method in `GraphicsForm` and call it from the parent form. Alternatively, you can put your saving logic in the parent form and expose the data to be saved via one or more public properties in `GraphicsForm`.